# how to write a xml data in to plist file in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xml, plist

how to write a xml data in to plist file in iphone? i am using this code
`  i m use this code
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

```
NSString *thexml=[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[webdata mutableBytes] length:[webdata length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains

(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);


NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
```

// NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mySettings" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/textfile.plist",

```
                      documentsDirectory];

//create content - four lines of text

//NSString *content = @"One\nTwo\nThree\nFour\nFive";
NSString *content =thexml;
NSLog(@"%@",thexml);
//save content to the documents directory

[content writeToFile:fileName 

          atomically:YES 

            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy 

               error:nil];
```

[self writePlist:1 fileName:thexml];
    [thexml release];
    [connection release];`

but i m see the plist file that display a file is a curuupted .?? pls give me a solution ....
thanks in advance